# Java Download File With Apache IO with Progress Bar

Tags: java, swing, file-io, progress, fileutils

Basically, I'm trying to find a way to download files with Java Apache IO Commons and have a swing progress bar.  I know how to download URL to file, using `FileUtils.copyUrlToFile();` and such, but how would I add a progress bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commons IO 2.0 and above do have [copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream source, File destination)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyInputStreamToFile-java.io.InputStream-java.io.File-), so you can use ProgressMonitorInputStream.

Comment: How would I use the ProgressMonitorInputStream with FileUtils?  I have this code, how would I get percent? http://pastebin.com/cQw6b4iz

Comment: Do you have the live example for that @eduardog3000 ?

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the methods of [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) accept an `InputStream` we can't use [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html), and I can't see any other way into that API that would give info. on progress, I think this idea is a non-starter.  It cannot be done.

Unless you are referring to copying multiple resources from `URL`(s) to `File`(s), then we could at least offer the progress of the group (e.g. "3 out of total of 5 files copied").

Comment: Is there any other api thing that would allow downloads with progress bars?